# MVC 3 Ajax requests heaping up

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code:

```
$('.defaultLink').click(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        cleardiv();
        $('#mainContent').empty()
        $('#mainContent').load(this.href).val();
        return false;
    });
```

This is to load a partial view into a div. Problem is, The GET Requests that i see in firebug seem to heap up, First there is one, then when i click again theres 2, then 4, 8 and so on.

This made me think that i need to clear the div thats being loaded into, but it doesnt seem to work, Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like another "click" handler is being registered everytime html is loaded into '#mainContent'. Is the snippet of JS above in the partial view you are loading into #mainContent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that each time you click, the number of events fired actually doubles? If so, is it possible that your click definition code (shown in your question) is being run multiple times? Put a break on it in Firebug and see. Also, put a break point on the server code to ensure that there really are multiple requests coming in.

Does your cleardiv() function clear mainContent? That would be redundant if you already have empty(). In fact, the load() should replace the contents as well.

Comment: I have checked and indeed it executes multiple times. The redundand code was simply out of desperation to try something that will work. Any Idea how i can clear the Click() method so it only executes once?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that because it should only execute once per click and I am mystified as to why you are getting multiple events. You have checked that there is nothing adding the click handler multiple times?

Comment: Fixed. Low point in my programming career. I had more than one binding to the click event of $('.defaultLink'). Dont know how I managed that but its fixed. Thanks!

Comment: For debugging, add an ev argument to your click handler: $('.defaultLink').click(function (ev) and inspect ev.currentTarget to see what is being clicked. It's a long shot but maybe the click is bubbling up to other .defaultLink elements. You can then also try ev.stopImmediatePropagation() and ev.preventDefault().

Comment: @Heinrich, that was the logical answer. I'm guessing you wrote that code at the end of a long day :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to control caching on the server. You can decorate your action/controller with:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

To prevent caching.

Also I'm pretty sure the '.val()' is not necessary following '.load()' although couldn't say for sure whether this was causing duplicate requests.

Comment: Oh yeah. I didnt realize about the val() being there! Thanx for the caching tip. But still, The requests keep coming.